# QODBC Invoice Table Query taking too long

Tags: mysql, qodbc

I am using the QODBC VB Demo to query the invoice Table in Quickbooks Desktop edition, but the query takes too long and it keeps running until the program crashes. I tried using TOP 10 (SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Invoice) but that doesnt help, is there a better way to do this? I need the data from the Invoice table, its a must.

Comment: Could you post text results of SHOW INDEX FROM invoice;  and  EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE .....?

Comment: I get no results, the query just keeps executing without returning any results.

Comment: Since it crashes, could you post your error log?  It may have some clues.

Comment: It freezes the VB, there is no error log is there?

Comment: OK, then post your my.cnf/ini from MySQL so we can help you determine if you have an error.log.  You and we should see information naming the error log file.